# npm create-react-app Error: EACCES: permission denied. The operation was rejected by your operating system

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code, terminal

I want to use react in vscode but when I try to install node.js it gives me errors. my command is

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/create-react-app
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/create-react-app'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/create-react-app'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/create-react-app'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -13,
npm ERR!     code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!     path: '../lib/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js',
npm ERR!     dest: '/usr/local/bin/create-react-app'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/create-react-app'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/create-react-app'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/defneyazicioglu/.npm/_logs/2020-03-23T17_10_48_130Z-debug.log
```

How can I solve this

Comment: just remove `-g` from command. You don't need to install `create-react-app` globally.

Comment: Error is because of you don't have permission.

Comment: use sudo npm install -g create-react-app

Comment: This is basically because your user doesn't have access to install npm module globally. There are two fixes that I know. 1. use Sudo to install the module. like `sudo npm install -g create-react-app` or 2. you can install node js without root access. find more info from here: https://medium.com/@nadun1indunil/do-not-sudo-npm-why-5b9adff8caa2.

Answer (score 3):

Try these commands :

1. $sudo -s
2. $npm install -g create-react-app
3. $exit
4. $npx create-react-app my-app